# How to get Prior value of picklist in LWC component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
 <lightning-record-edit-form
        object-api-name="Scenario__c"
        record-id={recordId}
        density="comfy"
        onsuccess={handleSuccess}
        onload={handleOnLoad}
        onsubmit={handleSubmit}
        onerror={handleError}>


  <lightning-input-field required="true" field-name={profilechange} variant="label-hidden" 
  onchange={handleprofilechange}></lightning-input-field>
     </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

I am using the record edit form and have a picklist field on UI. I have picklist values like Daily, Weekly, monthly, Yearly. I need to give an alert if the picklist value changed from Monthly to Daily or Yearly to Monthly.

So I need to get the prior value of the picklist to compare with the new value. I can get the new value using `event.detail.value` but am not able to get the previous value of the picklist.

How to get the previous value of the picklist field in LWC when we are using Record Edit form?

Answer (score 2):

`event.detail.value` will always return the current value.

you will have to to create a property to store the "original and previously" selected values on your own.
So, you can use your `handleOnLoad` function to get what the picklist is set to originally, and store it. then, everytime you change the value, store the "previous" one in that property to be able to compare against the current one.